# Where is OMSDataSet.xml (used by EZoms and EZomsRTD)?

Tags: rtd

Some times the user needs to wipe the cache of stored orders.  This could be done by deleting OMSDataSet.xml file.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

OMSDataSet for EZoms and RTD is located in:
C:\Users\Sgoldberg\AppData\Roaming\EZoms

You can also accomplish the same thing by using EZoms from the Menu:  
File -> Logout (then close the Login dialog box)
Edit -> Clear All

Then shut down Ezoms and start up RTD.

This will cause both apps to login and fetch all orders from the server.